# Swift / MotionKit.framework / how to update label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to exploit motion data. I've created a test app using the [MotionKit Framework](https://github.com/MHaroonBaig/MotionKit). `print(testString)` prints the `x` variables correctly to the console in an one second interval. But my testLabel will not be updated once.

```
import UIKit
import MotionKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

let motionKit = MotionKit()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    motionKit.getAccelerometerValues(1.0) { (x, y, z) -> () in
        let testString = String(x)
        self.testLabel.text = testString
        print(testString)            
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your textfield text code in dispatch_async

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
      self.testLabel.text = testString  
    });
```

Comment: thank you. that did it. could you explain me why? so I don't just copy/paste, but understand it, please ^^

Comment: All UI updated should be done on MainThread. Your motionKit.getAccelerometerValues runs on background thread so when you update your label on that thread it will not be updated to UI so to update the label on main thread you have to wrap it inside the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()... which executes on mainthread.